# In Splunk- How can I upload a file larger than 500MB?

Tags: logging, splunk

I'm trying to monitor a 3GB log file (IIS advanced log file) in Splunk,
but I get an error message:

```
File too large. The file selected is 3174Mb. Maximum file size is 500Mb
```

How can I upload a file larger than 500MB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I splited the file to smaller files using the split command (Linux):

```
 split -b 500m mybigfile.txt
```

And then I uploaded al the files one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I have uploaded a file more than 1GB for indexing on Splunk before.

Although the GUI limits the uploading to be under 500MB, you can upload the file to the server first and then index it as a local file.